# Custom loss function in tensorflow using list as penalty

Tags: python, tensorflow, customization, tensor, loss-function

I am new to tensorflow and have problems defining a custom loss function for a customer churn problem, which includes a list of values as penalty.

So far, I replicated a mean squared error function that penalizes wrong predictions with an integer.

```
def rfm_penalty(y_true, y_pred):
    penalty = # Integer value, to be replaced by list
    loss = tf.where(tf.less(y_true * y_pred, 0),
                penalty * tf.square(y_true - y_pred), # penalize negat. (wrong) preds 
                tf.square(y_true - y_pred)) # no penalty for pos. preds
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
```

This one works, but I'd like to modify it: Previously, I calculated a metric that measures the value of a customer, called RFM (for recency, frequency and monetary value of past purchases). This metric is an integer value from 3 to 12 that sums up the three metrics R, F and M. It is stored in a feature column of my df_train.

```
df_train['RFM_Score'] = [3,6,5,9,11,12,4,...,4] # same dimensions as y_true
```

I would like to use this feature column (or list) as penalty, thus penalizing wrong predictions higher for highly valuable customers. I would be happy for every idea to do that, even better with a sigmoid function, as its a binary classification case.

Thank you!

Comment: hi,did you find the answer?